# Heimdall error: Setting up interface failed!

Tags: linux, heimdall

While trying to know the pits available in my phone (Samsung GT-I9082, the Grand Duos) heimdall (in Linux) throwed me this error.

What does it mean?

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options here, let's do the easiest first:

1. Do **not** boot into Download mode from the "4 way menu" from the device, this will cause issues. Ensure you turn the device off and boot into recovery with the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons.
2. Ensure `USB Debugging` is enabled on the device.
3. Ensure [samsung-kies](/questions/tagged/samsung-kies) has no processes running, or just uninstall it completely. It causes a LOT of issues with USB Drivers.
4. Ensure you have the correct USB Drivers installed for your device.
5. Try a different USB port, and cable if possible.
6. Try deleting `/System/Library/Extensions/Heimdall.kext` and reinstalling Heimdall
7. Try running this command: `sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/heimdall.kext` if you get an error then point 3 is your error!
8. Ensure Heimdall has the correct permissions: `sudo chown -R root:wheel /System/Library/Extensions/heimdall.kext`
9. Reinstall your OS (Linux) from scratch (this is a rather **nuclear option** to be honest)

Finally this is more general for other users. If you are using a Mac OS run the following:

```
$ sudo kextunload -b com.devguru.driver.SamsungComposite
$ sudo kextunload -b com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMData
$ sudo kextunload -b com.devguru.driver.SamsungACMContro
```

Comment: Drivers? Do we need drivers for Heimdall on Linux?

Comment: Nope not necessarily (making this general for as many users as possible) for Linux only (generally) you need Udev rules set-up for your Samsung device, but some distributions of Linux need drivers. There's too many to cover, and I don't know which ones need which, so I'd guess not.

Comment: What is `kextunload`? You answer seems to be aimed at OSX, not Linux (the `/System` folder is an OSX thing). Am I missing something? What would the equivalent locations be in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was booting into download mode AFTER powering off my phone first. I used to go into boatloader mode directly while my phone was on.